# How to monitor if LogStash is fully loaded?

Tags: load, logstash

I am using LogStash to collect the usage logs of my service. I am wondering how could I know if a LogStash is fully loaded and should add more servers to handle the logs? I don't want to miss any of the logs.

Any suggestion would be helpful, thanks in advance:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, Logstash is only parsing the logs and send the logs event to a place to store, ex: Elasticsearch!

If you are using elasticsearch as your logs storage, you can try to install [marvel](http://www.elasticsearch.org/overview/marvel/). 
It is a plugin of elastcisearch, after you have install it, you want use it to view your log service status, ex: disk space, CPU, memory usage. 
So you want use it to monitor your service and know whether the service is fully loaded.

**Updated:**

As discuss in the comments, your output is `file`. 
What you need is an broker. Logstash default message queue is 20 events. So, when the queue is full, as your say, some logs will be drop. So, you need an broker to buffer your logs. The recommandate broker for logstash is `Redis`. You can run two Logstash instances, one is receive the logs from server, (input is tcp and output is redis), the other one is your indexer (input is redis and output is file).

Comment: I am using LogStash to receive data from 'tcp' input and then use 'file' output to store the logs in local files for further processing. So marvel is an incredible tool to monitor ES, however I need to monitor the status of LogStash itself.

Comment: Well, you say your output is file, so, it is no any fully loaded problem if you have enough space to save the logs!

Comment: Since the 'tcp' input uses ServerSocket to process the incoming requests, shouldn't we take care about the server status like CPU and memory usage? I am afraid of the LogStash cannot handle the volume of data and eventually some of data will be dropped.

Comment: I have update the answer. Please refer it. You need an broker to buffer your logs to prevent logs.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will add a Redis to prevent data losing:)