# When will LogStash exceed the queue capacity and drop messages?

Tags: redis, message-queue, logstash

I am using LogStash to collect the logs from my service. The volume of the data is so large (20GB/day) that I am afraid that some of the data will be dropped at peak time.

So I asked [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25397148/how-to-monitor-if-logstash-is-fully-loaded/25397505#25397505) here and decided to add a Redis as a buffer between ELB and LogStash to prevent data loss.

However, I am curious about **when will LogStash exceed the queue capacity and drop messages?**

Because I've done some experiments and the result shows that LogStash can completely process all the data without any loss, e.g., local file --> LogStash --> local file, netcat --> LogStash --> local file.

Can someone give me a solid example when LogStash eventually drop messages? So I can have a better understanding about why we need a buffer in front of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, Logstash queue is very small. Please refer to [here](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/life-of-an-event).

```
Logstash sets each queue size to 20. This means only 20 events can be pending into the next phase.
This helps reduce any data loss and in general avoids logstash trying to act as a data storage   
system. These internal queues are not for storing messages long-term.
```

As you say, your daily logs size are 20GB. It's quite large amount. So, it is recommended that install a redis before logstash. The other advantage for installing a redis is when your logstash process have error and shutdown, redis can buffer the logs for you, otherwise all your logs will be drop.

Comment: My team is new to LogStash, so I really need a solid example or scenario to convince my teammates that we need such a node to prevent data loss. BTW, to handle LogStash error and shutdown is a good point, thanks:)

Comment: You are welcome. If you have any problem, please kindly ask and let's discuss together.

Answer (score 0):

The maximum queue size is configurable and the queue can be stored on-disk or in-memory. (Strongly advise in-memory due to high volume).

When the queue is full, logstash will stop reading log messages and drop incoming logs.

For log files, logstash will stop reading further when tit can't keep up, it can resume reading later. It's keeping track of active log files and last read position. The files are basically acting like an enormous buffer, it's really unlikely to lose data (unless files are deleted).

For TCP/UDP input, messages can be lost if the queue is full.

For other inputs/outputs, you have to check the doc, whether it can support back pressure, whether it can replay missed messages if a network connection was lost.

Generally speaking, 20 GB a day is pretty low (even in 2014 when it was originally posted), we're talking about 1000 messages a second. logstash really doesn't need a redis in front.

For very large deployments (multiple TB per day), it's common to encounter kafka somewhere in the chain to buffer messages. At this stage there are typically many clients with different types of messages, flowing over a variety of protocols.